# OS X, add command to bash for compiled program

Tags: bash, macos, gap-system

I have installed a [GAP computer algebra system](http://www.gap-system.org/) into my Macbook Pro.

However, if I type 'gap', it will say in the terminal that:

```
bash: gap: command not found
```

How I can fix this?

```
 /Users/myusername/gap4r8/bin
```

is the location of the script that I can use to boot GAP (gap.sh).

I would like to start GAP in terminal by just typing gap.

Comment: Where is this PATH in OS X?

Comment: Janos, it still says that command not found.

Comment: That does not work in OS X Sierra.

Comment: Type "export PATH=$PATH:/User/myusername/gap4r8/bin" This will add the location of your executable to the path and allow you to execute with just the executable name.

Comment: This does not work, because there is no file `gap` in `gap4r8/bin` (but there is `gap.sh`). I usually put into `/usr/local/bin` a symlink called `gap`, which points to `/Users/myusername/gap4r8/bin/gap.sh` (I need to remember to update it if my GAP location changes). To create a symlink, first call `cd /usr/local/bin` to change to that directory, and then `ln -s /Users/myusername/gap4r8/bin/gap.sh gap` (edit path as needed). You may need sudo access for that.

Comment: For mathematical questions on GAP on Stackexchange framework, I recommend [the `gap` tag on Mathematics Q&A site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gap). Technical questions may have a better fate in GAP Support or GAP Forum - please see some guidelines and suggestions at https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/gap/info.